# How can I make the AssemblyInfo version of a C# .NET CF program propagate to the Explorer Properties window?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, versioning

It seems like if you compile a Visual Studio solution and have a version # in your AssemblyInfo.cs file, that should propagate to say, the Windows Explorer properties dialog. This way, someone could simply right click on the *.exe and click 'properties' to see the version #. Is there a special setting in Visual Studio to make this happen?

[example picture http://content.screencast.com/users/Pincas/folders/Jing/media/40442efd-6d74-4d8a-8e77-c1e725e6c150/2008-09-24_0849.png](http://content.screencast.com/users/Pincas/folders/Jing/media/40442efd-6d74-4d8a-8e77-c1e725e6c150/2008-09-24_0849.png)

Edit: I should have mentioned that this is, specifically, for .NET **Compact Framework** 2.0, which doesn't support AssemblyFileVersion. Is all hope lost?

Answer (score 6):

Note, that the *AssemblyFileVersion* attribute is not available under .NET **Compact Framework**!

See [this](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2004/11/assemblyfileversion-on-cf.html) article from Daniel Mooth for a workaround.

Comment: Finally, a CF developer answering a CF question :)

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE: This answer is for accessing the AssemblyInfo properties within a .NET CF 3.5 application. It does not propagate to the executable's "Properties" inside of Windows Explorer (but could be used to write to a file, to the console, or to display in the application)**

I know this is a very old question, but here is a solution I found using Reflection and Linq to get the "AssemblyInformationalVersion" (product version in newer Visual Studio projects).

First, I added this to the AssemblyInfo.cs (replace the string with whatever you want to use):

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0.0 Alpha")]
```

Then, you can use this method to pull out the attribute (I placed it inside a static class in the AssemblyInfo.cs file). The method get's an array of all Assembly attributes, then selects the first result matching the attribute name (and casts it to the proper type). The InformationalVersion string can then be accessed.

```
//using System.Reflection;
//using System.Linq;
public static string AssemblyInformationalVersion
{
    get
    {
        AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute informationalVersion = (AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute) 
            (AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())).Where( 
                at => at.GetType().Name == "AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute").First();

        return informationalVersion.InformationalVersion;
    }
}
```

To get the normal "AssemblyVersion" attribute I used:

```
//using System.Reflection;
public static string AssemblyVersion
{
    get
    {
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This still won't show in the Explorer properties window, as the OP is asking.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I didn't realize the OP was asking specifically about the built executable properties.

Potentially, you could print the attributes to a file (or display it in the application) but that's not really a nice solution. I've added a disclaimer to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Does the [AssemblyFileVersion attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute(VS.71).aspx) help?

Comment: Well, according to the msdn it says that "If the AssemblyFileVersionAttribute is not supplied, the AssemblyVersionAttribute is used for the Win32 file version," so I haven't tried it. Maybe I'll give it a try later and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another attribute:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.114.0")]
```

Note that you still need the AssemblyVerison one as well to correctly identify the assembly to the .NET runtime.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that attrib doesn't exist in CF, not in 2.00 at least

Answer (score 1):

The version number does propagate through to the "Version" tab in the properties dialogue but not through to the summary. Unfortunately VS will not auto-populate the summary information of a file as the information is meta-data attached to the file itself. You can however access and manipulate the summary information yourself by using the free DSO OleDocument Properties Reader from Microsoft.

You can acquire the library from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9BA6FAC6-520B-4A0A-878A-53EC8300C4C2&displaylang=en

Further information on its use can be found at: http://www.developerfusion.co.uk/show/5093/

**EDIT**: As noted above by pb and Nigel Hawkins you *can* get the property to propogate by using the AssemblyFileVersion attribute like:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.114.0")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that RevisionNumber is the correct field to be looking for.

Try explorer, right click -> version tab, and look at the AssemblyVersion field there.

Answer (score 0):

in my project we use FileVersion = YYYY.MM.DD.BUILD (e.g., 2008.9.24.1) but the ProductVersion should be major.minor.revision.BUILD.  we use the AssemblyInformationalVersion to get around this.

AssemblyVersion="MAJ.MIN.REV.1" --> used by .NET

AssemblyInformationalVersion="MAJ.MIN.REV.XXX" --> used in explorer's ProductVersion

AssemblyFileVersion="YYYY.MM.DD.XXX" --> used in explorer's FileVersion